# Error al cargar carpeta static en django con heroku

Tags: python, django, heroku

Buenas tardes a todos, presento un problema respecto a que ya configure la aplicacion de django, para que se ejecute en heroku, este paso ya lo logre, pero cuando carga la pagina, no carga todo lo que contiene la carpeta static, esta carpeta contiene el css, el js, y todo lo de diseño.
Esta es mi configuracion en settings.

settings.py

```
"""
Django settings for carlos_beta project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 1.8.1.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/settings/
"""

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
from django.conf.global_settings import TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS as TCP
import os
import dj_database_url
Temp_Path = os.path.realpath('.')
PACKAGE_ROOT = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))
#BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
PROJECT_ROOT = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))

TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = TCP + (
    'django.core.context_processors.request',
)
# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'i4hygaqx0xlccp%yv&p-vpw(t_w!y*zj9c95jf96f5@#m##e9$'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'allauth',
    'allauth.account',
    'allauth.socialaccount',
    'apps.home',
)

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
)

SITE_ID = 1

LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = "/"

EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.console.EmailBackend'

ROOT_URLCONF = 'carlos_beta.urls'

TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
    # Django default context processors
    "django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth",
    "django.core.context_processors.debug",
    "django.core.context_processors.i18n",
    "django.core.context_processors.media",
    "django.core.context_processors.static",
    "django.core.context_processors.tz",
    "django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages",
    # Required by allauth template tags
    "django.core.context_processors.request",
    # allauth specific context processors
    "allauth.account.context_processors.account",
    "allauth.socialaccount.context_processors.socialaccount",
)

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(PACKAGE_ROOT, 'template')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'carlos_beta.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]

# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

#STATICFILES_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')]
#STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR),'static')
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'staticfiles')
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'static'),
)

STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'whitenoise.django.GzipManifestStaticFilesStorage'

MEDIA_URL = 'http://localhost:8000/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'media')

DATABASES['default'] = dj_database_url.config()

SECURE_PROXY_SSL_HEADER = ('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO', 'https')

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']

DEBUG = False

try:
    from .local_settings import *
except ImportError:
    pass
```

y este es el orden de mis carpetas.

- carlos_beta

  - demo

    - .git
    - apps
    - carlos_beta

      - static
      - staticfiles
      - template
      - settings.py
    - media

Y esto es lo que aparece cuando aplico heroku logs:

```
2016-03-30T19:29:58.274840+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/static/js/cbpAnimatedHeader.c450e7852dc1.js" host=carlosbeta.herokuapp.com request_id=55b57b38-68b9-4059-bd03-d99761b74364 fwd="189.204.187.82" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=6ms status=404 bytes=317
2016-03-30T19:29:58.090240+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/static/js/classie.a9df1cfb76ce.js" host=carlosbeta.herokuapp.com request_id=0a3d86f5-0a0f-448a-ba5e-82f8419f2b04 fwd="189.204.187.82" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=9ms status=404 bytes=307
2016-03-30T19:29:58.368499+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/static/js/jqBootstrapValidation.dcd9f481ad3b.js" host=carlosbeta.herokuapp.com request_id=a0eaa344-32c7-4b00-98d2-e9583cfea4bd fwd="189.204.187.82" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=4ms status=404 bytes=321
2016-03-30T19:29:58.465555+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/static/js/contact_me.fc33c9e718bc.js" host=carlosbeta.herokuapp.com request_id=fd8a08c8-a40c-406e-beeb-5b6821414437 fwd="189.204.187.82" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=4ms status=404 bytes=310
2016-03-30T19:29:58.560948+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/static/js/freelancer.dab54c4a12f9.js" host=carlosbeta.herokuapp.com request_id=c4c11d89-9f9a-43e0-a05d-438e454cb360 fwd="189.204.187.82" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=6ms status=404 bytes=310
2016-03-30T19:29:58.679636+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=carlosbeta.herokuapp.com request_id=985c2d83-5a0c-4b12-b7b7-c0dc81ac9bc8 fwd="189.204.187.82" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=4ms status=404 bytes=285
2016-03-30T19:29:58.053328+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/static/css/freelancer.ae465281b891.css" host=carlosbeta.herokuapp.com request_id=cfa4d3e9-33db-4a65-ba09-c458c1cd26ce fwd="189.204.187.82" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=6ms status=404 bytes=312
2016-03-30T19:29:58.168049+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/static/js/freelancer.dab54c4a12f9.js" host=carlosbeta.herokuapp.com request_id=ad96b050-58b1-408a-9780-56269a09798e fwd="189.204.187.82" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=9ms status=404 bytes=310
2016-03-30T19:30:10.448385+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=carlosbeta.herokuapp.com request_id=298c956c-1cc2-4e51-80c7-eea73ea4c4a1 fwd="189.204.187.82" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=122ms status=200 bytes=10737
2016-03-30T19:30:10.545643+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/static/css/bootstrap.min.6240119d9b4f.css" host=carlosbeta.herokuapp.com request_id=08d17bbf-3693-46f3-b39c-052722df09ad fwd="189.204.187.82" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=6ms status=404 bytes=315
2016-03-30T19:30:10.565343+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/static/css/freelancer.ae465281b891.css" host=carlosbeta.herokuapp.com request_id=e7161863-b9aa-4997-b18b-02e04d5e66fc fwd="189.204.187.82" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=20ms status=404 bytes=312
2016-03-30T19:30:10.657519+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/static/js/jquery.3c9137d88a00.js" host=carlosbeta.herokuapp.com request_id=1ff88e46-d200-473f-a3ec-5606a4eabc8d fwd="189.204.187.82" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=8ms status=404 bytes=306
2016-03-30T19:30:10.677087+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/static/js/bootstrap.min.c5b5b2fa19bd.js" host=carlosbeta.herokuapp.com request_id=7eca8a50-36f5-4a12-ab53-5851c99899aa fwd="189.204.187.82" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=19ms status=404 bytes=313
2016-03-30T19:30:10.807526+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/static/js/freelancer.dab54c4a12f9.js" host=carlosbeta.herokuapp.com request_id=d72549a4-af27-4c54-b474-8a7f8a1b2d19 fwd="189.204.187.82" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=37ms status=404 bytes=310
2016-03-30T19:30:10.601054+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/static/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.feda974a77ea.css" host=carlosbeta.herokuapp.com request_id=d1c9c107-28db-4c09-9b2c-966d16d1ce90 fwd="189.204.187.82" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=49ms status=404 bytes=331
2016-03-30T19:30:10.797488+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/static/js/contact_me.fc33c9e718bc.js" host=carlosbeta.herokuapp.com request_id=e9992305-aca7-43ed-b11d-f94879898048 fwd="189.204.187.82" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=48ms status=404 bytes=310
2016-03-30T19:30:10.781915+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/static/js/classie.a9df1cfb76ce.js" host=carlosbeta.herokuapp.com request_id=081fcc11-8496-4f7b-9af2-c0d7e0718bce fwd="189.204.187.82" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=45ms status=404 bytes=307
2016-03-30T19:30:10.880986+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/static/img/logo.3d074b67708d.png" host=carlosbeta.herokuapp.com request_id=f397cd12-58c5-4ff4-aeba-edbb09f0681b fwd="189.204.187.82" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=6ms status=404 bytes=306
2016-03-30T19:30:10.790562+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/static/js/cbpAnimatedHeader.c450e7852dc1.js" host=carlosbeta.herokuapp.com request_id=cf7c9734-ed62-44ca-b966-fc2fef3e9cc9 fwd="189.204.187.82" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=50ms status=404 bytes=317
2016-03-30T19:30:10.797322+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/static/js/jqBootstrapValidation.dcd9f481ad3b.js" host=carlosbeta.herokuapp.com request_id=f421b2a2-9a96-4ad3-8813-277ee0020197 fwd="189.204.187.82" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=49ms status=404 bytes=321
2016-03-30T19:30:10.981896+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=carlosbeta.herokuapp.com request_id=87c3d1e9-c33a-40c8-99bc-86b68f1bdb31 fwd="189.204.187.82" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=8ms status=404 bytes=285
2016-03-30T19:30:15.541011+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/Registrar_Paciente/" host=carlosbeta.herokuapp.com request_id=2da2824c-5b56-4aeb-bb64-867602c95852 fwd="189.204.187.82" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=34ms status=200 bytes=9461
2016-03-30T19:30:15.646390+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/static/js/jquery.3c9137d88a00.js" host=carlosbeta.herokuapp.com request_id=dcbcb127-3ae5-40c1-a290-506b003156d0 fwd="189.204.187.82" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=3ms status=404 bytes=306
2016-03-30T19:30:15.642594+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/static/css/bootstrap.min.6240119d9b4f.css" host=carlosbeta.herokuapp.com request_id=14de13ab-2276-4445-83c1-9906e0e42a36 fwd="189.204.187.82" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=4ms status=404 bytes=315
2016-03-30T19:30:15.739074+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/static/js/classie.a9df1cfb76ce.js" host=carlosbeta.herokuapp.com request_id=60628b19-4868-47f6-9160-bb58a3a03942 fwd="189.204.187.82" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=6ms status=404 bytes=307
2016-03-30T19:30:15.646742+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/static/js/bootstrap.min.c5b5b2fa19bd.js" host=carlosbeta.herokuapp.com request_id=adbc1adc-c7e3-408c-a9a3-4ae67caee792 fwd="189.204.187.82" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=4ms status=404 bytes=313
2016-03-30T19:30:15.740927+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/static/js/cbpAnimatedHeader.c450e7852dc1.js" host=carlosbeta.herokuapp.com request_id=0cf183db-42f0-4842-a419-9b6597a70f33 fwd="189.204.187.82" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=3ms status=404 bytes=317
2016-03-30T19:30:15.635613+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/static/css/freelancer.ae465281b891.css" host=carlosbeta.herokuapp.com request_id=dde77633-fe8d-4e13-b2cf-e242d64e86d5 fwd="189.204.187.82" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=4ms status=404 bytes=312
2016-03-30T19:30:15.824096+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/static/js/freelancer.dab54c4a12f9.js" host=carlosbeta.herokuapp.com request_id=65216ea4-274c-4479-b70d-d9fe22f849c3 fwd="189.204.187.82" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=5ms status=404 bytes=310
2016-03-30T19:30:15.653945+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/static/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.feda974a77ea.css" host=carlosbeta.herokuapp.com request_id=25a8791e-5706-4961-8df7-9108116e6bb2 fwd="189.204.187.82" dyno=web.1 connect=6ms service=11ms status=404 bytes=331
2016-03-30T19:30:15.760725+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/static/js/contact_me.fc33c9e718bc.js" host=carlosbeta.herokuapp.com request_id=d073b461-9630-4bd3-8c01-259886d90a60 fwd="189.204.187.82" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=4ms status=404 bytes=310
2016-03-30T19:30:15.734108+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/static/js/jqBootstrapValidation.dcd9f481ad3b.js" host=carlosbeta.herokuapp.com request_id=11027e5d-c63e-47a2-a00b-eb8d8aaed423 fwd="189.204.187.82" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=8ms status=404 bytes=321
2016-03-30T19:30:24.209947+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/Crear_Post/" host=carlosbeta.herokuapp.com request_id=890dab8c-9292-4a1b-ae4c-1f8bd491f614 fwd="189.204.187.82" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=20ms status=200 bytes=9444
2016-03-30T19:30:24.327712+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/static/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.feda974a77ea.css" host=carlosbeta.herokuapp.com request_id=6b81bf22-5d3e-4cae-9b39-0e62e4dfb69b fwd="189.204.187.82" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=8ms status=404 bytes=331
2016-03-30T19:30:24.317375+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/static/css/freelancer.ae465281b891.css" host=carlosbeta.herokuapp.com request_id=b84493cf-23a7-48c4-8385-ca9734dcb8bd fwd="189.204.187.82" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=4ms status=404 bytes=312
2016-03-30T19:30:24.320782+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/static/css/bootstrap.min.6240119d9b4f.css" host=carlosbeta.herokuapp.com request_id=b38a4885-044d-438a-bfa8-6818c4eec4aa fwd="189.204.187.82" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=7ms status=404 bytes=315
2016-03-30T19:30:24.420308+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/static/js/classie.a9df1cfb76ce.js" host=carlosbeta.herokuapp.com request_id=dd533f74-af40-4c22-abe7-556dcf4363b3 fwd="189.204.187.82" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=4ms status=404 bytes=307
2016-03-30T19:30:24.423199+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/static/js/cbpAnimatedHeader.c450e7852dc1.js" host=carlosbeta.herokuapp.com request_id=f0cfc54d-50fb-4505-ba12-0f264fcbc85e fwd="189.204.187.82" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=4ms status=404 bytes=317
2016-03-30T19:30:24.395970+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/static/js/jquery.3c9137d88a00.js" host=carlosbeta.herokuapp.com request_id=54169d83-7d8c-4d89-8e2c-322b19171ed0 fwd="189.204.187.82" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=4ms status=404 bytes=306
2016-03-30T19:30:24.405710+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/static/js/jqBootstrapValidation.dcd9f481ad3b.js" host=carlosbeta.herokuapp.com request_id=3bf8e96f-ad07-47b1-83d4-bc4318520dc6 fwd="189.204.187.82" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=12ms status=404 bytes=321
2016-03-30T19:30:24.405058+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/static/js/bootstrap.min.c5b5b2fa19bd.js" host=carlosbeta.herokuapp.com request_id=7ce1659e-52b0-4e23-9db7-e9bf79f6e77f fwd="189.204.187.82" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=4ms status=404 bytes=313
2016-03-30T19:30:24.508065+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/static/js/contact_me.fc33c9e718bc.js" host=carlosbeta.herokuapp.com request_id=64303f23-5009-451f-8bc7-3155473f52bc fwd="189.204.187.82" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=7ms status=404 bytes=310
2016-03-30T19:30:24.525041+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/static/js/freelancer.dab54c4a12f9.js" host=carlosbeta.herokuapp.com request_id=d52e496e-32a2-434e-82cf-9a9088837bf2 fwd="189.204.187.82" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=16ms status=404 bytes=310
2016-03-30T19:30:31.223125+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=carlosbeta.herokuapp.com request_id=f8d6d6da-64d8-4658-bb1a-468408dbd85e fwd="189.204.187.82" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=48ms status=200 bytes=10737
2016-03-30T19:30:31.341621+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/static/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.feda974a77ea.css" host=carlosbeta.herokuapp.com request_id=ff3aacfd-8d27-449b-a59a-92090b670507 fwd="189.204.187.82" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=15ms status=404 bytes=331
2016-03-30T19:30:31.351087+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/static/js/jquery.3c9137d88a00.js" host=carlosbeta.herokuapp.com request_id=f4b4c8a1-937a-42df-a4db-71222ad359e1 fwd="189.204.187.82" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=18ms status=404 bytes=306
2016-03-30T19:30:31.347124+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/static/css/bootstrap.min.6240119d9b4f.css" host=carlosbeta.herokuapp.com request_id=b9d48f7d-9ba4-44e0-8d57-e9d7f673eb69 fwd="189.204.187.82" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=16ms status=404 bytes=315
2016-03-30T19:30:31.509324+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/static/js/freelancer.dab54c4a12f9.js" host=carlosbeta.herokuapp.com request_id=740b3cb4-2c59-4669-8ef8-b8c27f2fb7a4 fwd="189.204.187.82" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=6ms status=404 bytes=310
2016-03-30T19:30:31.452474+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/static/js/classie.a9df1cfb76ce.js" host=carlosbeta.herokuapp.com request_id=918f43fd-7833-4d26-aded-6f7f71539606 fwd="189.204.187.82" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=24ms status=404 bytes=307
2016-03-30T19:30:31.468936+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/static/js/cbpAnimatedHeader.c450e7852dc1.js" host=carlosbeta.herokuapp.com request_id=cc4eb2fa-1d64-4c04-9dac-ca728d415f90 fwd="189.204.187.82" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=38ms status=404 bytes=317
2016-03-30T19:30:31.439592+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/static/js/bootstrap.min.c5b5b2fa19bd.js" host=carlosbeta.herokuapp.com request_id=a8b4a0e9-4559-40c0-9633-eece6ad767d4 fwd="189.204.187.82" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=11ms status=404 bytes=313
2016-03-30T19:30:31.478534+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/static/js/jqBootstrapValidation.dcd9f481ad3b.js" host=carlosbeta.herokuapp.com request_id=e8706179-d18d-4705-9fdb-4c86b5569d35 fwd="189.204.187.82" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=34ms status=404 bytes=321
2016-03-30T19:30:31.460256+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/static/js/contact_me.fc33c9e718bc.js" host=carlosbeta.herokuapp.com request_id=f01ecc3f-82d5-454f-b47f-2c136e90d0fd fwd="189.204.187.82" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=15ms status=404 bytes=310
2016-03-30T19:30:31.339106+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/static/img/logo.3d074b67708d.png" host=carlosbeta.herokuapp.com request_id=2ae5e6bd-8914-41f5-b9bb-c2b4324c2848 fwd="189.204.187.82" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=10ms status=404 bytes=306
2016-03-30T19:30:31.341646+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/static/css/freelancer.ae465281b891.css" host=carlosbeta.herokuapp.com request_id=d35cefe5-db42-4255-a2d0-8eaedd749ecb fwd="189.204.187.82" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=12ms status=404 bytes=312
2016-03-30T19:32:12.080930+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/accounts/login/" host=carlosbeta.herokuapp.com request_id=13046bd9-b04c-4493-a838-ee46dbeec082 fwd="189.204.187.82" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=131ms status=200 bytes=10356
2016-03-30T19:32:12.189798+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/static/css/freelancer.ae465281b891.css" host=carlosbeta.herokuapp.com request_id=f3276a4d-beca-4d49-9e9d-f760a1345895 fwd="189.204.187.82" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=4ms status=404 bytes=312
2016-03-30T19:32:12.293156+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/static/css/bootstrap.min.6240119d9b4f.css" host=carlosbeta.herokuapp.com request_id=fee39e8f-d550-4282-beb3-24c7ec8bb8b8 fwd="189.204.187.82" dyno=web.1 connect=3ms service=4ms status=404 bytes=315
2016-03-30T19:32:12.368543+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/static/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.feda974a77ea.css" host=carlosbeta.herokuapp.com request_id=d5884d96-a6cc-4b1f-a92d-068df8a98ac3 fwd="189.204.187.82" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=10ms status=404 bytes=331
2016-03-30T19:32:12.388840+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/static/js/bootstrap.min.c5b5b2fa19bd.js" host=carlosbeta.herokuapp.com request_id=2d3f4110-355c-466f-9e8a-a6304670daec fwd="189.204.187.82" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=12ms status=404 bytes=313
2016-03-30T19:32:12.360790+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/static/js/classie.a9df1cfb76ce.js" host=carlosbeta.herokuapp.com request_id=658a5835-28e8-49e1-bfe7-58d683b05d12 fwd="189.204.187.82" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=7ms status=404 bytes=307
2016-03-30T19:32:12.399372+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/static/js/cbpAnimatedHeader.c450e7852dc1.js" host=carlosbeta.herokuapp.com request_id=f652950b-46e9-4b77-a899-731a4944326b fwd="189.204.187.82" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=4ms status=404 bytes=317
2016-03-30T19:32:12.370444+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/static/js/jquery.3c9137d88a00.js" host=carlosbeta.herokuapp.com request_id=c14dc174-de17-497d-a0ee-5421416b6de3 fwd="189.204.187.82" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=13ms status=404 bytes=306
2016-03-30T19:32:12.397030+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/static/js/jqBootstrapValidation.dcd9f481ad3b.js" host=carlosbeta.herokuapp.com request_id=68ab7f04-ac87-499a-b7a8-7791031e2335 fwd="189.204.187.82" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=5ms status=404 bytes=321
2016-03-30T19:32:12.470857+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/static/js/freelancer.dab54c4a12f9.js" host=carlosbeta.herokuapp.com request_id=2cd5d539-6164-4f88-92a5-484a27db59a2 fwd="189.204.187.82" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=4ms status=404 bytes=310
2016-03-30T19:32:12.457372+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/static/js/contact_me.fc33c9e718bc.js" host=carlosbeta.herokuapp.com request_id=923952fd-f5bf-4a40-8621-e8c8592f0bd1 fwd="189.204.187.82" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=8ms status=404 bytes=310
2016-03-30T19:32:15.953152+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/Registrar_Profesionista/" host=carlosbeta.herokuapp.com request_id=3c80281d-549b-4e78-b77b-3697f9d836f0 fwd="189.204.187.82" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=54ms status=200 bytes=9469
2016-03-30T19:32:16.077483+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/static/js/jquery.3c9137d88a00.js" host=carlosbeta.herokuapp.com request_id=f0c97629-cbab-4662-a36f-f2939be03157 fwd="189.204.187.82" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=9ms status=404 bytes=306
2016-03-30T19:32:16.065482+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/static/css/bootstrap.min.6240119d9b4f.css" host=carlosbeta.herokuapp.com request_id=baf11b98-98a0-47e9-9091-7c22ea8b1012 fwd="189.204.187.82" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=7ms status=404 bytes=315
2016-03-30T19:32:16.088090+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/static/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.feda974a77ea.css" host=carlosbeta.herokuapp.com request_id=78986faf-31c7-40cc-9a18-8ec5a607051b fwd="189.204.187.82" dyno=web.1 connect=2ms service=12ms status=404 bytes=331
2016-03-30T19:32:16.069713+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/static/js/bootstrap.min.c5b5b2fa19bd.js" host=carlosbeta.herokuapp.com request_id=7b3904c0-ee03-4941-ba6e-2b6256b461c7 fwd="189.204.187.82" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=3ms status=404 bytes=313
2016-03-30T19:32:16.058177+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/static/css/freelancer.ae465281b891.css" host=carlosbeta.herokuapp.com request_id=e9fc7940-2d9a-45a9-a835-4cda03811979 fwd="189.204.187.82" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=5ms status=404 bytes=312
2016-03-30T19:32:16.165678+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/static/js/jqBootstrapValidation.dcd9f481ad3b.js" host=carlosbeta.herokuapp.com request_id=5c89dce2-eeb8-4d6c-aa2c-1329d4fbb99f fwd="189.204.187.82" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=4ms status=404 bytes=321
2016-03-30T19:32:16.219142+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/static/js/freelancer.dab54c4a12f9.js" host=carlosbeta.herokuapp.com request_id=722d09f2-1707-46c7-95e6-3abd21303427 fwd="189.204.187.82" dyno=web.1 connect=2ms service=4ms status=404 bytes=310
2016-03-30T19:32:16.173905+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/static/js/cbpAnimatedHeader.c450e7852dc1.js" host=carlosbeta.herokuapp.com request_id=afedafee-120c-4e59-b397-d52fa1a57cc8 fwd="189.204.187.82" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=11ms status=404 bytes=317
2016-03-30T19:32:16.177892+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/static/js/classie.a9df1cfb76ce.js" host=carlosbeta.herokuapp.com request_id=cfb17f88-d91a-4a14-94d6-c6135cfa6088 fwd="189.204.187.82" dyno=web.1 connect=7ms service=5ms status=404 bytes=307
2016-03-30T19:32:16.199158+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/static/js/contact_me.fc33c9e718bc.js" host=carlosbeta.herokuapp.com request_id=8dda0303-63fc-4527-9498-99abd21cad8b fwd="189.204.187.82" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=4ms status=404 bytes=310
2016-03-30T19:56:33.216645+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=carlosbeta.herokuapp.com request_id=841a4372-08b4-41b8-b098-24869d7d9d8b fwd="189.204.187.82" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=66ms status=200 bytes=10737
2016-03-30T19:56:33.328803+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/static/css/bootstrap.min.6240119d9b4f.css" host=carlosbeta.herokuapp.com request_id=3af98fc7-9400-43b1-9965-bf8fa6e90eb8 fwd="189.204.187.82" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=4ms status=404 bytes=315
```

Comment: Cuando haces el despliegue a Heroku, ¿qué te sale en el log?

Comment: ya acabo de agregar los logs en la pregunta inicial

Comment: afecta que haya creado una carpeta staticfiles?

Comment: Los archivos estáticos deberían estar en tu carpeta `staticfiles` que es la carpeta que tu has definido para copiar tus archivos estáticos mediante el comando `manage.py collectstatic`

Comment: si, de hecho eso es lo que hice, ya que heroku lo hace automaticamente, mi duda mas bien seria si esta bien configurado el settings.py en cuanto a la direccion de static.

Comment: De antemano hombre, tienes mal la dirección url de media, dice localhost, y tu ya estás en producción.

Comment: si, ya me fije en ese detalle, y lo acabo de resolver, pero aun sigo con el detalle de que no carga el static, gracias :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fue hace mycho y ya no recuerdo en que post fue, pero fue en el stackoverflow en ingles y esto es lo que encontre que tenia que hacer en mi settings.py cuando se me presentaron inconvenientes para usar los archivos en mi carpeta static

```
import os
#para asegurarse de que la carpeta base siempre sea la misma
#sin importar si la carpeta del proyecto se mueve de ubicacion
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


STATICFILES_DIRS = (os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static/'),)
STATIC_URL='/static/'
```

En tu caso seria:

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = (os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'demo/carlos_beta/static/'),)
STATIC_URL='/static/'
```

Al principio de todos los archivos html hay que cargar la carpeta de static

```
{% load static %}

<html>
....
</html>
```

Espero haberte ayudado

Comment: Gracias, de hecho ya encontre la respuesta hace tiempo, solo que estaba ocupado, en la documentacion de heroku en github, encontre la respuesta https://github.com/heroku/python-getting-started